# how to use the sql character array wilcard?

Tags: sql, db2, wildcard

Hi I am using SQL DB2 and trying to find all values in a column that start with `F25` and end with any character that does not contain `..`

So for example the following are allowed

```
F2501
F25AB
F25ab
F25A.
```

I had imagined I could do something like:

```
where col like 'F25[!..]'
```

however this reutrns no rows where I know such codes exist i.e. `F25AB`.

what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: have to use `not contains()` or `position()`

Comment: you can use `where col like 'F25%' and right(col,2) <> '..'`

Answer (score 2):

Neither `[` nor `!` is a wildcard in SQL.

The **only** wildcards that SQL `LIKE` supports are `%` for any number of characters and `_` for a single character.

To do what you want, use

```
where col LIKE 'F25%' -- starts with F25
  and col NOT LIKE '%..'  -- does not end with ..
```

Comment: hmm w3schools mentions charlists as a form of wildcard? http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_wildcards.asp

Comment: I wonder if `locate_in_string(col,'..',-1) <> length(col) -2` is faster than NOT LIKE

Comment: @brucezepplin: w3fools is known to be full of errors.

Comment: @brucezepplin -- that is only valid for SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

Try regular expresión by using xquery. Or if you hace db2 luw 11.1 you can use regular expresión functions directly from SQL.